# How to remove empty lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have some list like below. Now I want to remove all of [] list.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since empty lists evaluate to `False` with `bool`, you can use `filter` with `None`. Note `L` may be any iterable of lists, you need not begin with a list of lists.

```
L = [['JOB', 'APPLIED', 'FOR'], [], [], [], ['TEST'], ['SOMETHING ELSE']]

res = list(filter(None, L))

print(res)

[['JOB', 'APPLIED', 'FOR'], ['TEST'], ['SOMETHING ELSE']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [['a','b'],[],['c','d']]
print([i for i in l if i])
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

First store all the data into a list so your new list looks like

```
list=[[],[],[],['Job Applied for'],[],[],['My name']]
```

then write

```
for i in list:
    if i==[]:
       list.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using conventional for loops:

```
x=[[9,8,7],[2,3],[5,7],[],["a","b"],[]]
y=[]

for i in range(0,len(x)):
    if len(x[i])!=0:
        y.append(x[i])
            
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[[9, 8, 7], [2, 3], [5, 7], ['a', 'b']]
```

Using List Comprehension( Simplified way ):

```
x=[[9,8,7],[2,3],[5,7],[],["a","b"],[],[1,2,3],[]]
y=[ i for i in x if i ]
print(y)
```

Outcome:

```
[[9, 8, 7], [2, 3], [5, 7], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3]]
```