# Python Check if any of lists is not empty, and if not do something with corresponding folder that is linked to that list

Tags: python, list, optimization

So here I am trying to optimize some code I have.

Code checks if any of lists is empty, and if it is not, corresponding folder that is linked to that list will be saved in external program, so to make it more clear this is code:

```
if len(match_FIRST)>0 and len(match_SECOND)>0 and len(match_THIRD)>0 and len(match_FOURTH)>0:
  keep = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD', 'FOURTH']
elif len(match_FIRST)>0 and len(match_SECOND)>0 and len(match_THIRD)>0 and len(match_FOURTH)==0:
  keep = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD']
elif len(match_FIRST)>0 and len(match_SECOND)>0 and len(match_THIRD)==0 and len(match_FOURTH)>0:
  keep = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'FOURTH']
elif len(match_FIRST)>0 and len(match_SECOND)==0 and len(match_THIRD)>0 and len(match_FOURTH)>0:
  keep = ['FIRST', 'THIRD', 'FOURTH']
elif len(match_FIRST)>0 and len(match_SECOND)>0 and len(match_THIRD)==0 and len(match_FOURTH)==0:
  keep = ['FIRST', 'SECOND']
elif len(match_FIRST)>0 and len(match_SECOND)==0 and len(match_THIRD)>0 and len(match_FOURTH)==0:
  keep = ['FIRST', 'THIRD']
... etc
```

So basically we will in this way keep in keep= [] list only names that are linked to lists that are not empty...

What do you suggest any algorithm that can optimize this since now when I have only four lists it is easy to manually check it this way... but better solution is needed...

Please advice!

Thanks,

Salute

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove empty lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000248/how-to-remove-empty-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking to [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) only non-empty lists from your list of lists.

Another way to do the same thing is to use a comprehension with `if` as filter:

```py
non_empty_lists = [l for l in lists if len(l) > 0]
```

For example:

```py
>>> lists = [
...     ['a', 'b', 'c'],
...     [],
...     [],
...     ['d', 'e']
... ]
>>> non_empty_lists = [l for l in lists if len(l) > 0]
>>> non_empty_lists
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]
```

Comment: You don't actually have to check the length. An empty list is considered falsey, and so you can simplify using ```if l``` at the end of the comprehension .

Comment: I know, I just prefer to be more explicit with conditions. `is not None`, `len() > 0`, etc. `bool(obj)` tests for both of these without distinction

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am actually trying not only to filter non-empty lists, but more important to fill keep=[] list correct accordingly...  so I not need "list" of not empty lists, but corresponding "name"